# Plone recently modified list

Tags: plone

I need to save the recently modified list into a text file.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance,
Michele

Answer (score 1):

waiting an answer a reached a quick solution!
I've modified the recently_modified template to show the complete list of items modified (changing the number of item to show). Copy & paste the items name in a txt file ... and the problem is solved!